# resizing the image in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Recently i started creating a social network WP7 application. In that while sending web request for user data they are giving a url for user image while callback. My issue is while binding this image i am getting images in different sizes. ie Its hard to keep the image size uniform. Because of this the user interface looks pretty ordinary. What i need to do for make this image size uniform. Writing a converter or other solution. Can any one please help me to resolve this issue. I tried giving width, height and fill property but still getting the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
WriteableBitmap resizedImage = new WriteableBitmap(imageToResize);//imageToResize is BitmapImage
using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, isf))
                    {
                        double maxHeight = newWidth;
                        double maxWidth = newHeight;
                        double scaleX = 1;
                        double scaleY = 1;
                        if (pixHt > maxHeight)
                            scaleY = maxHeight / pixHt;
                        if (pixWt > maxWidth)
                            scaleX = maxWidth / pixWt;
```

```
                    double scale = Math.Min(scaleY, scaleX);
                    int newWidth1 = Convert.ToInt32(pixWt * scale);
                    int newHeight1 = Convert.ToInt32(pixHt * scale);

                    resizedImage.SaveJpeg(isfs, newWidth1, newHeight1, 0, 70);
                    isfs.Close();
                }
            }
```